# Is this complex exponential conversion correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to convert $5\cos(100\pi t + 25)$ to a complex exponential.

I get that Euler's formula is such that $\cos(nt) = \frac{1}{2}(e^{nit} + e^{-nit})$.

I have my answer as $\frac{5}{2}(e^{(100\pi i(t+25)} + e^{-100(\pi i(t+25)})$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not correct because the $100$ multiplies the $25$ in your solution, while it does not in the original.  You should use the angle sum formula to get the $25$ out of the argument of the cosine.

Comment: So would 5cos(100πt+25) become 5(cos(100πt)cos(25)-sin(100πt)sin(25)) ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Now the arguments of the trig functions match Euler's formula

Comment: I've done that, would it therefore be $\frac{5}{2}\left(\cos\left(25\right)\left(e^{\left(100\pi it\right)}+e^{-100\pi it}\right)-\frac{\sin\left(25\right)}{i}\left(e^{100\pi ix}-e^{-100\pi it}\right)\right)$

Comment: At a first glance that appears correct, but I didn't check carefully.  Now you have the choice of how to present it.  Maybe you think the $e^{\pm100\pi i t}$ is the important part and you distribute things to multiply that.  Everything else is just a constant.  I would, but that doesn't mean you should.